# YouTube Data API with JavaScript search request returns error

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-data-api

I followed the example provided [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript#search_by_keyword), created and registered my application in the Google developer console, added my Client Id to the authentication, enabled the YouTube Data API for my application and even enabled billing in my account and this is the error message I get:

*Code 403: Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.*

I have also tried the following:

- regenerate the client id
- creating and adding the API key to the request
- Enabled other authentication/youtube APIs

Here is the full response:

```
[
 {
  "error": {
   "code": 403,
   "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
   "data": [
    {
     "domain": "usageLimits",
     "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
     "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
     "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
    }
   ]
  },
  "id": "gapiRpc"
 }
]
```

Any thoughts on this?